# Dúvida em consulta banco de dados, erro na consulta

Tags: html, java-ee, jsp

**Estou fazendo um trabalho sobre sistema de venda de passagens Java Web e estou com uma dúvida no meu codigo para trazer esses dados exemplo:
No select consulto 3 campos da minha tabela: origem, destino e data
o problema que não esta trazendo nenhum dado, foi testado direto no banco e funciono.**

Exemplo Pratico:

- RIO DE JANEIRO - SÃO PAULO - 20/08/2015
- RIO DE JANEIRO - SÃO PAULO - 23/08/2015
- RIO DE JANEIRO - SANTA CATARINA - 20/08/2015

Consulto esses dados por um formulario e depois jogo em uma tabela.
SQLFIDLE da minha tabela: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/478f3/1

**Consulta:**

```
public ArrayList<Passagem> consultar(Passagem p) {
    try {
        Connection conexao = getConexao();
        PreparedStatement pstm = conexao.prepareStatement(
            "Select * from passagem where " +
            "origem = ? " +
            "AND destino = ? " +
            "AND data = ?");

        pstm.setString(1, p.getOrigem());
        pstm.setString(2, p.getDestino());
        pstm.setString(3, p.getData());

        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<Passagem> listaPassagens = new ArrayList<Passagem>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            p.setIdpassagem(rs.getInt("idpassagem"));
            p.setOrigem(rs.getString("origem"));
            p.setDestino(rs.getString("destino"));
            p.setData(rs.getString("data")); 
            p.setPartida(rs.getString("partida"));
            p.setChegada(rs.getString("chegada"));
            p.setValor(rs.getInt("valor"));                 

            listaPassagens.add(p);
        }

        pstm.close();
        conexao.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaPassagens;
}
```

**Tabela do Banco de dados:**

```
CREATE TABLE passagem(
idpassagem NUMBER(5,0),
origem VARCHAR2(50),
destino VARCHAR2(50),
data VARCHAR2(255),
partida VARCHAR2(255),
chegada VARCHAR2(255),
valor NUMBER(8,2),
PRIMARY KEY(idpassagem)
);
```

**Formulario que busco os dados:**

```
<form action="passagem.jsp" method="post">  
        Cidade Origem:
        <input type="text" name="origem">
        <br>
        <br>
        Cidade Destino:
        <input type="text" name="destino">
        <br>
        <br>
        Data:
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="data" > 
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="busca"/>
    </form>
```

**Onde recebo os dados e mostra em uma tabela:**

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="AdicionarCarrinho.jsp"> 
    <table border="1">
        <th>Selecione Passagem</th>
        <th>Cidade Origem</th>
        <th>Cidade Destino</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Partida</th>
        <th>Chegada</th>
        <th>Preço(R$)</th>
        <th>Id Onibus</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <%
         PassagemDAO pdao = new PassagemDAO();
         Passagem p = new Passagem();

         if(request.getParameter("origem") != null && request.getParameter("destino") != null 
                 && request.getParameter("data") != null){

            p.setOrigem(request.getParameter("origem"));  

            p.setDestino(request.getParameter("destino"));

            p.setData(request.getParameter("data"));   


            ArrayList<Passagem> lista = pdao.consultar(p);

         for(Passagem p2 : lista){
        %>      


              <tr>
                <td align="center">  <input type="checkbox" name="comprar_ <%= p2.getIdpassagem() %>" value="Sim"> </td>
                <td> <%= p2.getOrigem() %> </td>
                <td> <%= p2.getDestino() %> </td>
                <td> <%= p2.getData() %>" </td>
                <td> <%= p2.getPartida() %> </td>
                <td> <%= p2.getChegada() %> </td>                  
                <td> <%= p2.getValor() %></td>
                <td> <%= p2.getIdonibus() %> </td>
                <td align="center">  <input type="text" name="quantidade_<%= p2.getIdpassagem() %>" size="1" maxlength="3" value="1"> </td>

            </tr>

        <%  
          }  
         }
        %>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Adicionar ao Carrinho" name="Submit">
            <input type="reset" name="Limpar" value="Limpar"> </p> 
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**O problema agora agora que não retorna nenhum dado como foi dito, está dando esse erro:**

Advertência: The web application [/rodoviario] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

**Estou usando o netbeans com o servidor Glafissh e Banco de dados Oracle.**
**Em detalhe da data está em String, quando consulto uso o formulario ali em cima que passo um type="text" uso o datepicker do Jquery, fazendo as consultas separadas funciona normal, o problema é fazer em conjunto: retorna em branco e no log do glafish da o erro acima, se alguém tiver alguma solução para esse problema.**

Comment: nao entendi a pergunta... o que você deseja retornar da query ?

Comment: Não deu pra entender nada, o que tu queres que a `query` retorne?

Comment: tenho um formulario, que faço a busca de Cidade Origem, Cidade Destino e Data, minha query faz a busca, porém está trazendo os dados independentes, precissava trazer os dados especificos pesquisados.

Comment: O que tu quer dizer com dados *independentes*?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, tu queres digitar no teu **form** uma **cidade origem**, uma **cidade destino** e uma **data** e trazer *apenas um* dos registros que tens no banco de dados?

Comment: reformule a pergunta

Comment: que nem o exemplo ali em cima, pesquisei uma passagem de São paulo para Rio de Janeiro com data 20/08/15, certo?, teria que trazer somente esse dado, porém está trazendo outros, que tem como cidade origem 'São Paulo', etc..

Comment: Sim tenho uma tabela de Banco de dados com esse dados, precisso consultar e mostra.

Comment: @Rafilds, edita a pergunta e põe esses detalhes que tu falou nos comentários, senão toda informação fica dispersa.

Comment: @Rafilds, está retornando algum erro ou simplesmente não traz nenhum resultado?

Comment: ja foi editado la em cima, está retornando 1 erro e a consulta em branco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consegui solucionar o problema, obrigado a todos pela atenção e tentar me ajudar, problema muito noob, o erro tava no Insert, não sei porque mais não esta aceitando pesquisar Origem e Destino com acentuação, exemplo: â,é,í,ô, fiz novos inserts sem acentuação e funcionou normal.**

Falto colocar na JSP:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>

html  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Jéferson Bueno está correta!

Você deseja encontrar os registros que

origem = 'ORIGEM' **E(ao mesmo tempo)** destino = 'DESTINO' **E(ao mesmo tempo)** data = 'DATA'

Assim você deve utilizar o operador `AND`

O problema é que você esta fazendo `pstm.setString(3, p.getData())`. Está tentando fazer **setString passando uma data**:

#### **ISSO NÃO FUNCIONA!**

Para solucionar o problema, você pode tentar converter o seu date para `String` da seguinte forma:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
// aqui use o formato de data compatível com o que está no banco,  
//conforme bem lembrado pelo @JonasCruvinel
String strData = formatter.format(p.getData());
...
pstmt.setString(3, strData);
```

Ou senão trocar `pstm.setString(3, p.getData())` para `pstm.setDate(3, p.getData())`.

Se ainda assim não funcionar, o problema é que o `Timezone` do seu computador (ou o que o Java está utilizando) está diferente do banco de dados

Comment: então cara mais na minha tabela como foi dito, Data esta como String e ja passo no formato certo, e ja recebo no formato certo usando type="text" do formulario, uso datepicker do jquery.

Comment: o seu passagem.getData( ) é uma string ?

Comment: sim, até tenho outro projeto usando data como Date, porém esta com o mesmo problema que esse, não acredito que seja o problema de data.

Comment: então o seu problema agora é com o driver do banco.. a consulta está correta! penso que você deve abrir outro tópico relatando o erro com o driver

Comment: sim, foi aberto o tópico aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81926/erro-registered-the-jdbc-driver-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-but-failed-to, obrigado, estou tentanto resolver, qualquer novidade eu aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Se é que eu entendi a tua dúvida, tu só precisas usar `AND` ao invés de `OR` na tua claúsula `where`.

Ex.:

```java
PreparedStatement pstm = conexao.prepareStatement(
"SELECT * FROM passagem WHERE " +
"origem = ? " +
"AND destino = ? " +
"AND data = ?");
```

Comment: eu fiz isso porém não retorno nenhum dado, o que pode ser o problema?

Comment: A combinação que tu está buscando existe no banco?

Comment: sim, coloquei minha tabela la em cima.

Comment: Cara, aquilo não faz diferença. O que interessa são dados da tua tabela, faça um **sqlfiddle** para eu poder ver os dados.

Comment: meu sqlfidle para entender melhor: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/478f3/1

Comment: Qual o tipo de retorno de `Passagem.getData()`?

Comment: acabei de posta o código la em cima, para entender melhor

Comment: retorna a data que digitei, fiz o teste 1 por 1 separado, problema foi quando faz a consulta em conjunto não sei porque, estou tentando entende.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo primeiramente altere o OR para AND

PreparedStatement pstm = conexao.prepareStatement(
"SELECT * FROM passagem WHERE " +
"origem = ? " +
"AND destino = ? " +
"AND data = ?");

Como o Jeferson citou.
E como o Pedro citou.

O banco de dados sql trabalha com data no formato americano.
AAAA-MM-DD

Você provavelmente esta digitando no formato brasileiro DD/MM/AAAA

Salve o valor digitado pelo usuario em uma string e converta a string para o padrao americano antes de realizar a consulta como eu fiz em um site meu.

data = Year(TxTDataSincronismo.Text) & "-" & Month(TxTDataSincronismo.Text) & "-" & Day(TxTDataSincronismo.Text)

Comment: bem lembrado... adicionei na minha resposta uma observação quanto a isso

Comment: Eu fiz o teste no próprio banco, o sql está correto, a data eu passo como string e no formulário estou usando datepicker do jquery, quando ponho o AND, aparece o seguinte erro na saído do netbeans, usando glafish como servidor e oracle como banco de dados:  **Advertência:   The web application [/rodoviario] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.**

Comment: a minha data no banco como está na tabela la em cima, to usando String, e já fiz o insert nesse formato: ** INSERT INTO passagem(idpassagem, origem, destino, data, partida, chegada, valor, idonibus)
VALUES(1, 'São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro, '05/10/2015', '11:00', '12:00', 15, 1);
**

Comment: Já verificou o valor que o datapicker retorna quando vc seleciona uma data? 

publica a query do sql que vc esta utilizando

Comment: sim, retorna a data normal, apenas notei que tem vezes que retorna a data = 20/08/2015"   <--- com 1 aspas, ja foi publicado.