# Erro registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister

Tags: java, html, oracle, jsp, glassfish

Estou fazendo um sistema *JavaWeb* usando `jsp` que está nesse tópico: [Dúvida em consulta banco de dados, erro na consulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81720/d%C3%BAvida-em-consulta-banco-de-dados-erro-na-consulta), e em uma consulta com o banco de dados, me deparei com um erro de driver que está logo abaixo. Uso o IDE `netbeans` com servidor `glassfish` e o banco de dados Oracle.

### Erro:

> **Advertência**: *The web application [/rodoviario] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.*

### Classe de conexão:

```
public class Conexao {

private Connection conexao;

public Conexao() {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"rafilds","1234");
  } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConexao() {
    return conexao;
}
}
```

Comment: relacionado a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered

Comment: parece ser apenas um warning, nao um erro

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido, isso não era erro como dito pelo Pedro, é um warning, e o problema era no insert do banco de dados.

Comment: Será que poderia complementar sua resposta. Ela poderá ajudar mais pessoas no futuro. Lembrando também que você pode aceitar sua própria resposta.